# Using author description for resources listing blog

Tags: seo, copyright

I'm working on a new blog that collects resources for web developers like lists of available CMS, Frameworks, Libraries and other plugins. I want to use the author description for every item as is from its website and telling that this is the author description and of course with a link back to that site where it will be available for download (not on my site).

Will I be infringing copyright or will my SEO be penalized for duplicating content maybe?

Here is an example of what a post will look like:

[image]

Comment: I will let someone else answer this, however, Google likes original content, or when content is cited or borrowed, it likes value-add on the page. For example ratings, comments, etc. It would be best if you keep this in mind as you go along and see what you can add to each that is unique. Perhaps you can review some of the software yourself on your site. Maybe get a few trusted people to write reviews. Who knows. Just a thought that might help.

Comment: Could you include an example in your question? For example, how would your entry about [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) look like?